# Как соединить массивы в один массив с уникальными значениями?

Tags: javascript, массивы, merge

Не судите строго, я изучаю JS. У меня задачка, у меня массив из 30 элементов (фактически также массивы). Как соединить в новый масив оставив только уникальные элементы.

```
[ "history", "american", "crime" ]
[ "french", "fiction", "english" ]
[ "magical", "history", "french" ]
[ "mystery", "english", "american" ]
```

И это должно примерно выглядеть так:

```
[ "history", "american", "crime", "mystery", "english", "french", "fiction" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так.

```js
var array1 = [ "history", "american", "crime" ];
var array2 =[ "french", "fiction", "english" ];
var array3 =[ "magical", "history", "french" ];
var array4 =[ "mystery", "english", "american"];

var result = Array.from(new Set([ ...array1, ...array2, ...array3, ...array4]));

console.log(result);
```

```js
    var array = [[ "history", "american", "crime" ],
                 [ "french", "fiction", "english" ],
                 [ "magical", "history", "french" ],
                 [ "mystery", "english", "american"]];

    var result1 = Array.from(new Set(array.flat()));

    console.log(result1)
```

Comment: В вызове `array.flat(1)` аргумент `1` можно опустить

Comment: @AndreiKhotko да конечно